# Convert a tensor into numpy array, but with higher precision

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Using TF2 and converting a tensor into an array by calling `.numpy()` on it works well, but returns a `float32`, I need a higher precision numpy array.

Having read even the source, I cannot find a way to do this.

EDIT:
Adding some code, to show how I am grabbing the vectors.

```py
model = tf.saved_model.load('./use_lite_saved_model')
sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.Load('./use_lite_saved_model/assets/universal_encoder_8k_spm.model')

def create_vector(sentence):
    global sp
    global model
    values, indices, dense_shape = process_to_IDs_in_sparse_format(sp, [sentence])
    tensors_out_dict = model.signatures['default'](
        values=values,
        indices=indices,
        dense_shape=dense_shape
    )
    tensor_out = tensors_out_dict['default']
    return tensor_out.numpy()[0]
```

Comment: You can convert the NumPy array to higher precision after retrieving it (as in `.numpy().astype(np.float64)`), but that will just give you the same value taking twice as much memory. If you want to have your tensors computed with higher precision, then you need to create them as such. When you create your inputs, specify `dtype=tf.float64` wherever necessary and then the rest of tensors will get the same type.

Comment: Strange - I am using a TF Hub module (USE), and when saving the output vector as a list, it has a higher precision as compare to converting to numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

**NumPy** uses **64-bit** precision by default, while **TensorFlow** uses **32-bit**.
This is because 32-bit precision is generally more than enough for neural networks,
plus it runs faster and uses less RAM.

If you still want the Tensor to be in higher prcesion, you can use tf.cast or after converting to **NumPy** you can change the dtype as follows.

```
values =  tf.constant([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])
```

**Returns:**

```
tf.Tensor([1. 2. 3. 4. 5.], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

To change the precision using `tf.cast`:

```
values_float64 = tf.cast(values,dtype=tf.float64)
```

**Returns:**

```
tf.Tensor([1. 2. 3. 4. 5.], shape=(5,), dtype=float64)
```

To change the precision using NumPy astype:

```
values.numpy().astype(np.float64)
```

**Returns:**

```
dtype('float64')
```

But if you are creating tensor from NumPy array which uses float64 by default, the same will be maintained in Tensor.

```
numpy_array = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])

tesor_from_numpy = tf.constant(numpy_array)
```

**Returns:**

```
tf.Tensor([1. 2. 3. 4.], shape=(4,), dtype=float64)
```

Hope I have answered your question, Happy Learning!

Comment: @dendog -  If you think I have answered your question, Please UpVote and accept the answer, Thank You.